# how to write a query based on its column

Tags: mysql

I have a table named TableA, as below;

```
+----+---------------+--------------+--------------+
| Id |  Frequency    | Inserted_Date| Eligibility  |
+----+---------------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | Halfyearly    |   23/8/2013  |              |
|  2 | Quaterly      |   24/11/2013 |              |
+----+---------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Here Eligibility column is initially empty.I need to write a query where Eligibility is set to be yes /no based on the frequency for current month.

**for 1st record,
as of today Eligibility=No**

**for 2nd record,
as of today Eligibility=Yes**

```
+----+---------------+--------------+--------------+
| Id |  Frequency    |Inserted_Date | Eligibility|
+----+---------------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | Halfyearly    |   23/8/2013  |   No         |
|  2 | Quaterly      |   24/11/2013 |   Yes        |
+----+---------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I have no idea how to write a query for getting the above output and more over i need to change it for every month.

Please help me out.

Thank you all in advance for your response.

Comment: 1. Store dates using a DATE data type 2. (Usually) Don't store data that can be easily calculated on the fly. And shouldn't that be eligibilililility? ;-)

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I can't tell how you're determining the value of `Eligibilility`. In fact, I can't tell what the table represents either.

Comment: @OGHaza im ll be doing this change every month. so the current month im checking whether this record is eligible or not.

Comment: Maybe if you add more example data it will be more clear - Ahh, I might understand, if Inserted date is `2013-01-01` and Frequency was `Halfyearly`, then `Eligibility = 1` if current month is `Jan 2013, Jul 2013, Jan 2014, Jul 2014 etc..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand it, if `Inserted_Date = Jan 2013` and `Frequency = 'Halfyearly'`, then `Eligibility = 1` when the current month is  `Jan 2013, Jul 2013, Jan 2014, Jul 2014 etc..`

```
UPDATE TableA
SET Eligibility = CASE WHEN (Frequency = 'Halfyearly' 
                            AND MONTH(Inserted_Date) % 6 = MONTH(NOW()) % 6) 
                         OR (Frequency = 'Quarterly' 
                            AND MONTH(Inserted_Date) % 3 = MONTH(NOW()) % 3)
                      THEN 'Yes'
                      ELSE 'No' 
                 END
```

If you have Annually as well you can just check

```
MONTH(Inserted_Date) = MONTH(NOW())
```

See this working on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7b7e/1)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
UPDATE TableA 
SET ELIGIBILITY = CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()) = DATEPART(MM,DATE)
                  THEN 'YES'
                  ELSE 'NO' END
```

Comment: i using this query in a stored procedure, which is triggered every month.so Eligibility column will be changed correspondingly

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE..WHEN

```
UPDATE tbl
SET Eligibility = 'Your value' Frequency WHEN 'Half Yearly' THEN 'No'
                                WHEN 'Quarterly' THEN 'Yes'
```

Comment: based on Inserted_Date , i need to set the value for Eligibility.

Answer (score 0):

"based on Inserted_Date , i need to set the value for Eligibility."

Then use

```
UPDATE tbl
SET Eligibility = CASE WHEN InsertedDate='' THEN 'No'
                            WHEN '' THEN 'Yes'
```

Comment: in the first row, Inserted_Date='23/8/2013' , then Eligibility= yes for the month of august and february, for rest of the other months Eligibility =No.

Comment: Do you have column to store the month's name?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the required output with below query:

```
SELECT ID,
       Frequency,
       Date,
       (CASE
           WHEN TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'mm') = TO_CHAR (Date, 'mm')
           THEN
              YEligibilility
           ELSE
              NEligibilility
        END)
          AS Eligibilility
  FROM (SELECT ID,
               Frequency,
               Date,
               'Yes' AS YEligibilility,
               'No' AS NEligibilility
               From TableA);
```