# Why do people on SO prefer CASE WHEN to other alternatives?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have noticed that on SO a lot of people seem to prefer `CASE ... WHEN` to other alternatives.

For example all of the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20191925/how-to-write-a-query-based-on-its-column/20191989#20191989) use `CASE ... WHEN` whereas I would have used a simple `IF`. `IF` is quite a bit less to type and is prevalent in all programming languages so it seems kind of weird to me that not a single answer uses it. (I would also expect that `IF` is a bit faster though I did not measure it).

Even more interesting are the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43159291/php-mysql-order-by-first-column-if-second-null/43159353#43159353). 2 out of 3 answers (among them the accepted answer) suggest using `CASE ... WHEN` when from my point of view `COALESCE` is the better solution (after all `COALESCE` was created for exactly the problem the OP has). (Also, in this case I am almost certain that `COALESCE` would be faster.)

So, my question is, is there any benefit to `CASE ... WHEN` (that offsets the additional typing) that I am missing or is it a case of "To a man with a hammer, everything looks like a nail"?

Comment: Old habits, they've learned something and don't care about learning more.

Comment: I thought so but it is used literally everywhere so I was wondering if I am missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One reason, a good one actually, is that a `CASE WHEN` expression is ANSI compliant while `IF` is not.  Were someone to face porting a MySQL query to another database the `IF` calls in MySQL would probably all have to be rewritten.

MySQL, like most databases, extended ANSI by introducing the `IF()` function.  Perhaps `IF`, or something similar to it, will become part of the standard some day.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I will still use `IF` for my `MySQL` only development though ;)

Answer (score 3):

`CASE WHEN` is in the SQL standard. `IF` is not. As SQL databases do have vastly different dialects, it is not the worst idea to stick to code that will work on most databases for the following reasons:

- If you build the habit of using code that is specific to one database, you will have troubles when working on another.
- If you use code that is specific to one database, you cannot test your query with other databases by simply copy pasting them. You can also not migrate your application to other databases without changing your SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

`CASE WHEN` is the ANSI standard expression for conditional expressions.  `IF()` is a function specific to MySQL.

In general, I prefer ANSI standard functionality when available -- although there are occasional exceptions.

Specifically about `IF()` as a function.  It is easily confused with `IF` as a statement in MySQL.  Using it as a function seems like unnecessary confusion (admittedly, there are other databases where `CASE` can be confused with a `CASE` statement in the scripting language, but that is not an issue in MySQL).

In addition, `IF()` is pretty close to control flow, which makes it different from most other functions anyway.

Comment: `.. IF() is pretty close to control flow, ...` IMO `if(...)`  **is** flow control, where `case when ...` yields an *expression* (just like the ternary `?:` in C)